# Ошибка Xcode 7 SKTexture: Error loading image

Tags: ios, xcode, spritekit

Есть кусок написанного приложения на Objective-c содержащий 14 картинок-иконок, в эмуляторе Xcode 7 запускается отлично, никаких ошибок, все картинки как нужно выводятся на экран.

Но когда запускаю на Ipad mini iOS 8.4.1, то в консоли вываливается ошибка `SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "picture_name"` на 2 картинки объекта из 14ти, при этом на экране на месте этих картинок изображение с красным иксом, все остальные объекты-картинки отображаются корректно. Файлы `.png` - все проверил.

Возможно кто-то сталкивался с похожим и подскажет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько вариантов:

- симулятор игнорирует строчные и заглавные буквы и находит любые названия. Убедитесь, что названия файлов в проекте совпадают с реальными.
- убедитесь, что изображения подключены в текущий target.
- убедитесь, что формат файлов поддерживается (насколько я помню, для .png и т.д. не надо указывать расширение)
- ну и конечно убедиться что файлы целые и открываются вьюерами.

Comment: Спасибо. Первый пункт вашего ответа помог))